# Can excel calculate either cell on the relationship between the two cells?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to build a basic financial tools sheet for myself. Here's a problem:

Let's make Cell B1 30 times of cell A1 (B1 = 30*A1). However I'm not sure when A1 is a known value or B1 is.

What I need is when I fill 100 in A1, B1 will be filled with 3000 (30xA1) automatically, and if I fill 60 in B1, A1 will be filled 2 (1/30 of B1).

Is it possible?

Comment: Then you need vba macro. You can do it by formula only.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. If that's the case I'd pass for now.

Comment: So have the user enter the starting value in D1 and then use if() with relevant calculations ie D1 or D1 x 30

Comment: @SolarMike not sure how it can work. Can you clarify?